# Increase Line spacing in IEEE reference style

Tags: bibliographies

[image]

I am using IEEEtran to format my references in IEEE format as a part of my thesis work. My project supervisor wants me to increase the line spacing in references section. I am using .bib file for my references. 
Please refer to the attached image. The references have very little line spacing by default.  I want to have something like double line spacing in the reference section also. How should I do it ?

Comment: Are you using `biblatex` or the `.bst` files that come with `IEEEtran`? Can you show us an MWE/MWEB of what you have so far?

Comment: You could try for instance `\linespread{1.5}\selectfont` just before `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`. I'm not sure if this is what you want to do.

Comment: I am using filename.bib  for the references section (TexStudio). 
     `\linespread{1.5}\selectfont` does not achieve the desired objective

Comment: I think there was a typo in @llbant's comment: The advice should be to write `\linespread{1.5}\selectfont` immediately before the `\bibliography` instruction.

Comment: The line space has increased using the above comment of @Mico. Is it possible to change the font too ?

Comment: @ShiS - Glad the comment was helpful. Regarding your follow-up query: Please be more specific. Otherwise, the only sensible (though not exactly illuminating!) answer is, "yes".

Comment: Any news here? The comment that worked for you seems to imply you don't use `biblatex`, so your question is tagged incorrectly.

Comment: I am using a .bib file in TexStudio and MikTex. I am not sure if biblatex is the same thing or something else. Please change the tags if someone finds something wrong. As regards the previous comment, I realized that font change was not needed, that is why I didn't pursue it further. Also, the comment by @Mico solved my problem, so it can be considered as the final solution to the above query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change line-spacing in a LaTeX document, either for the document as a whole or for selected parts, it's a good idea to load the [setspace](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/setspace/) package in the preamble. Then, if the linespacing needs to be increased just for the bibliography, simply issue the instruction

```
\setstretch{1.5}
```

immediately before `\bibliography{...}` if you use BibTeX, or immediately before `\printbibliography` if you use `biblatex`.

Aside: Loading the `setspace` package and issuing a `\setstretch` directive is safer, in general, than using the low-level TeX macros `\baselineskip` and `\linespread`.